# Netbeans IDE problem : when I cout << "Hello World" << endl; in the output there is only one letter which is H

Tags: c++, netbeans

when I `cout << "Hello World" << endl;` in the output there is only one letter which is just H.

I am really new to the programming stuff so I don't know what exactly might be the problem but you can check out the screenshots below.

So when I try to print "Hello World" it prints just H instead. Please help me solve the problem I really want to learn programming.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: first image]

When I run it, the output is just

> H
>
> RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 119ms)

[image: second]

The next screenshot shows the NetBeans C/C++ options:

[image: third]

Comment: It may be the IDE text encoding. If the text is in an multibyte encoding there may be some byte interpreted as a null char after the H.

Comment: Images of text are not accessible, nor are they searchable. Where possible they should be either augmented with the text they contain, or replaced with the text properly formatted in the editor.

Comment: you can see the pictures now :)

Comment: Your program is ok. Try to run it in your terminal, seems to be your IDE doing weird stuff.

Comment: so what is the solution ?

Comment: Are sure you're running the program displayed in the editor?

Comment: Does it matter that your `main()` does not take `argc` or `argv`?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too, and this is how **I fixed it**,

1- **Right click** on your **project file** ,
2- **Properties** ,
3- **Run** ,
4- **Console Type**  ,
5- Choose **Standard output** instead of Internal ,
6- Click OK...